# Plant is singular and complex is plural. How that can happen that they can come together

Tags: grammar

A product states it is enriched with "plant derived complex".

Here plant is singular and complex is plural. How that can happen?

Comment: "Complex" is a singular noun. The plural is "complexes". But in addition to that, I think you could have a situation where something plural (more than one material) could be derived from just one source. E.g. "cheese and butter from organic cow's milk"

Comment: It seems you have **a** complex about the plurality of the singular noun . . . (In the sentence, the only problem is that **a** is missing. And, stylistically, it should perhaps be *a plant-derived complex*, with a hyphen.)

Answer (score 1):

"Complex" is singular. It means a combination of interconnected things, and in particular, a type of chemical structure of several molecules bonded together. Chemical complexes are often used in medicines, and beauty products.

In this case, the "complex" is made from plant material, instead of being made from mineral oil, or animal flesh. It could be made from one plant or from many types of plant.

This is advertising, since plant-derived material is thought to be more natural, and so healthier.